# Getting the value of highlighted/marked text

Tags: react-native

I'm really new to React Native (but quite experienced in React) and i'm having some issues with my react native app and was hoping to get some help.

What i'm trying to achieve is that I want to be able to select and highlight a word in a text, then store that value in a variable.

In native javascript to retrive the word would be something like "window.getSelection()", but that obviously doesnt work in this case. At the moment I have only found solutions using TextInput, but I want the text to be static.

Anyone have any suggestions how to tackle this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean you want to have static text (presumably in a <Text> component) and have the user manually highlight the text, like click-and-drag-highlight, and then save whatever they've selected?

Comment: exactly like that! Sorry if that wasn't clear from the text :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<TextInput>` with a `editable={false}`

### UPDATE

As far as I know, there is no way to get the highlighted string directly but you can handle this with a trick!
use a `setInterval` and call `Clipboard.getString()` to get the string that is copied to clipboard!

[ref1](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/clipboard) - [ref2](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-clipboard)

Comment: When using this, I'm not longer able to highlight any text.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misunderstand what you have posted!

Comment: I like this approach! Thank you so much for the tip! That will certainly do the trick!